# PCIe bus bandwidth

Tags: bus, bandwidth, pcie

> Calculate the bandwidth of a PCIe link with 8 lanes, 8b/10b encoding and 2.5 GHz frequency.

I tried the following formula but I am not sure of its correctness:

BW = lane data rate × encoding × no. of lanes × efficiency  = 2.5 GHz × 0.8 × 8 × 1 = 16 GHz

Comment: The BW is usually specified in bits or bytes: e.g. 16 Gbps, 2 GB/s

Comment: Also, is this PCIe link uni- or bi-directional? If bi-directional, you'd add a x2 multiplier.

Comment: You have an 'efficiency' term in that equation which you've then given a value of 1. That then looks like you found that equation somewhere rather than produced it yourself - is that the case? Just want to be sure if you understand reasons for the terms in the equation. The efficiency is a ratio of the frame protocol bits (what actually goes up the wires) to the payload data bits within packets, at some agreed/specified payload data amount. As an aside, efficiency would normally include the encoding so 'payload data efficiency' or similar would be a closer term here.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct.

For a single lane, the bandwidth is basically the data rate. In your case, each symbol carries 8 bits plus 2 bits for encoding (overhead). This makes the data rate 2.5 GHz * 8/10 = 2 Gbps.

For 8 lanes, the bandwidth will be number of lanes times data rate: 2 x 8 = 16 Gbps.